# Should I call FreeLibrary explicitly after loading unamanaged DLL dynamically

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a `static class NativeMethods` containing methods decorated with `[DllImport]`.
I want to load DLL dynamically with LoadLibrary in `NativeMethods` static constructor.

Should I call FreeLibrary explicitly on some (process/AppDomain?) shutdown event?
Is letting OS do the cleanup implicitly on process shutdown reserved for the crashes only or a normal case?

Comment: Why do you need this? `DllImport` does this automatically and unloads library when the program exits. Anyway, you can do this using LoadLibrary with PInvoke, it will be unloaded as well when the program exits.

Comment: IMHO you should not mix up "[DllImport]" with "LoadLibrary", but from you question it is not clear if you want to do this or if you want to *replace* your current [DllImport] solution by dynamic binding. Please clarify.

Comment: I want to do it dynamically, just not sure why I should write binding code for every method when the attribute can do all of this for me. I only need to supply it with dll. Dll is in embedded resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this explicitly. The proper way would be to create a class that holds the library reference, which releases the reference in it's finalizer, just like with any other long living native resource.

It's tempting to just wait for the OS to cleanup (and it will clean it up on process exit, no worries about that), but it can introduce some hard to track issues when you're expanding your software, and it can make many issues (like hanging threads) worse in the long term.